# find the area of the region bounded by graphs

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

full question since I can't do the formatting thing in the title: find the area of the region bounded by graphs $y^2=-x$, $x-y=4$, $y=-1$, and $y=3$

I've drawn the graphs but I'm unsure how to approach the problem. I'm supposed to use double integrals but I don't know how to set that up.

here are the graphs
[image]

Comment: As $y$ varies from $-1$ to $3$, $x$ varies from the parabola to the diagonal line.

Comment: Note that interchange of axes is beneficial for computing area

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$$\int\limits_{y=-1}^3 (y+4)+y^2 dy = \frac{88}{3}$$

Comment: Hi David, What's that little piece of the region missing in the upper left (easy to see when plotted in blue, below)?  I see this once-in-a-while.  *Mathematica* doesn't quite complete the region with `ImplicitRegion[]`.  Is there a way to cause it to give a fuller region?

Comment: `PlotPoints->100`

Comment: Great!  Thank you!  That cleans it up!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can supply $f_1$ and $f_2$.

$ \displaystyle \int _{-1}^{3} \left( \int_{f_1}^{f_2} dx \,
\right)$ dy

The point is that you are integrating the function "1" within the area defined by the four "curves".

[image]